# How to copy file without using XP_CMDSHELL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008. I would like to give users possibility to copy files. Is it possible without using XP_CMDSHELL procedure? Cause i should not change permisions for that.

The error when i try to do Copy using XP_CMDSHELL is :

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell',
>   database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

Comment: The correct approach is **not to do this in SQL!** Do it in your application layer.

Comment: CLR stored proc. Or SSIS.

Comment: Put the copy command into a queue table, and have a background scheduled task in Windows (could be PowerShell, C#, cmd, what have you) that checks the queue table and performs the work. SQL Server should not be directly interacting with the file system (one of the reasons xp_cmdshell is disabled by default and why, even when it is enabled, you don't get access to it).

Comment: @RhysJones i want to take it away from application = ).
AaronBertrand It will not allow me to let it work fast, like person is clicking some file to copy and wait some time.
TabAlleman Gonna try it. It will allow me to copy files?

Comment: SQL Server is a wonderful tool to manipulate sets of data not files on the file system. You are asking if you can use a (fill in name of favorite sports car here) to move your house full of furniture from point a to point b. Its possible but probably very clunky.

Comment: Everyone will tell you this is a bad idea. So you should consider that this is a bad idea and you should not do it this way.